# JHipster integration tests fail when I used liquibase to change model data

Tags: spring, postgresql, h2, jhipster, liquibase

Summary: I updated my classes, test classes and my database to login with email. I wrote a liquibase's changelog to make database's changes.
Running the project, all worked fine but if I execute integration tests liquibase's changelogs are working bad.

What I think that it is happening:

1. I try to execute tests.
2. H2 database is initialized with every changelog (initial and customs)
3. Tests begin to be executed.
4. Before every tests, H2 database is not deleted but changelogs are invocated (or only my custom changelog).
5. My custom changelogs fails because it cannot find login column that was deleted on point 2 and It was not "restaurated" by initial
   changelog.

Complete version: I had generated a JHipster application with 4.8.0. My .yo-rc.json:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.company.name",
      "nativeLanguage": "es"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.8.0",
    "baseName": "name",
    "packageName": "com.company.name",
    "packageFolder": "com/company/name",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "hibernateCache": "no",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "buildTool": "gradle",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "secret",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "useSass": true,
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "es",
    "languages": [
      "es"
    ]
  }
}
```

I wanted to drop login column from JHI_USER and drop unique constraint from JHI_USER's email and make it not null, then, I made every code changes that I needed (I removed every reference to login and I changed them to email) and coded three liquibase changelog's files:

a) 20170913130000_drop_login_column_JhiUser.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
    <changeSet id="20170913130000" author="svalero">
        <dropColumn columnName="login" tableName="jhi_user" />
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

B) 20170913180000_drop_unique_constraint_email_JhiUser.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
    <changeSet id="20170913180000" author="svalero">
        <dropUniqueConstraint constraintName="jhi_user_email_key"
            tableName="jhi_user" />
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

C) 20170913182100_add_notnull_constraint_email_JhiUser.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd
                        http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
    <changeSet id="20170913182100" author="svalero">
        <addNotNullConstraint columnDataType="varchar(100)"
            columnName="email"
            tableName="jhi_user"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

I also added them on master.xml and everything worked perfectly on the application (./gradlew and yarn start).

But, when I tried to execute integration test (./gradlew test) I got this on every test:

```
com.company.name.web.rest.AuditResourceIntTest > getNonExistingAudit FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException
                Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException
                    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException
```

From tests results I found this:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/company/name/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20170913180000_drop_unique_constraint_email_JhiUser.xml::20170913180000::svalero:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Constraint &quot;JHI_USER_EMAIL_KEY&quot; not found; 
     SQL statement: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.jhi_user DROP CONSTRAINT jhi_user_email_key [90057-196] [Failed SQL: ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.jhi_user DROP CONSTRAINT jhi_user_email_key]
```

Then, I thought that on every test my custom changelog were invocated but the initial changelog were not invocated because my changelog cannot find columns or constraint that initial changelog must create.

My first "walkaround" was easy, add preconditions to changelogs like:

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN" onError="MARK_RAN">
    <columnExists columnName="login" tableName="jhi_user" schemaName="public" />
</preConditions>
```

But Liquibase does not have a precondition to "unique constraint" and I found this to check if "jhi_user_email_key" constraint exists:

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN" onError="MARK_RAN">
    <sqlCheck expectedResult="1">select count (*) from pg_constraint where conname='jhi_user_email_key'</sqlCheck>
</preConditions>
```

But in H2 (JHipster use this kind of database to tests) we do not have a pg_constraint and this does not work.

Finally, what is wrong? Why are tests running only my changelogs and they ignore initial changelog? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On JHipster 4.10.0 or up and thanks to @duderoot it is created like this:

```
        <column name="email" type="varchar(100)">
            <constraints unique="true" nullable="true" uniqueConstraintName="ux_user_email"/>
        </column>
```

Then, you can drop this constraint with this name without problems on any enviorement.

---

On JHipster 4.8.0, an "unique constraint" is created like this:

```
        <column name="email" type="varchar(100)">
            <constraints unique="true" nullable="true"/>
        </column>
```

They do not use "uniqueConstraintName" and constraint's names are different on every database.

On Postgresql (dev profile), "jhi_user_email_key" exists but on H2 (test profile) it does not exists.

To solve this, you can add uniqueConstraintName on Initial Schema:

```
        <column name="email" type="varchar(100)">
            <constraints unique="true" nullable="true" uniqueConstraintName="jhi_user_email_key"/>
        </column>
```

Or make differents changelogs with "dbms" preconditions.

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile I created a [PR 6460](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6469) on JHipster which was merged and I guess its gone be part of the next release 4.9.1. The name of the unique constrain is ***ux_user_mail*** i.e. your file **B)20170913180000_drop_unique_constraint_email_JhiUser.xml** should be change to:

`.....
<dropUniqueConstraint constraintName="ux_user_mail"
            tableName="jhi_user" />
.....`

Still, dropping the LOGIN column will have consequences on the login process i.e. you need to change the method **getUserWithAuthorities** of the **UserService** class e.g.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public User getUserWithAuthorities() {
    return userRepository.findOneWithAuthoritiesByEmail(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin()).orElse(null);
}
```

and **loadUserByUsername** in DomainUserDetailsService class:

```
 @Override
@Transactional
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String login) {
    log.debug("Authenticating {}", login);
    String lowercaseLogin = login.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
    Optional<User> userFromDatabase = userRepository.findOneWithAuthoritiesByEmail(lowercaseLogin);
    return ........
```

Also the **UserRepository** will need to be enriched with a search method e.g.

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = "authorities")
Optional<User> findOneWithAuthoritiesByEmail(String email);
```

On the other hand you will also need to remove the login property of the domain class User. It will not be enough just to remove the *@Column* annotation. Even if the property *login* is in the class without a *@Column* annotation, hibernate is gone trow a SchemaManagementException because JHipster naming strategy is configured like this

```
jpa:
    hibernate:
        naming:
            physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
            implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
```

and will gone expect a column login to exist into *jhi_user* table. The documentation of the naming strategy can be found [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#naming).

For your second liquibase changeSet * 20170913180000_drop_unique_constraint_email_JhiUser.xml* I will recommend you to verify if the constraint *jhi_user_email_key* exist.

This will give you the possibility to use email for login. Still by removing the *login* property from the the domain class *User* yo will need to refactor some classes from production and also from test code

Comment: Thank you for your answer but It is no real my problem. When I wrote on my question that "I made some code changes" I mean that I did the changes that you said. But tests fail because my liquibase custom changelog is executed in every tests but Initial changelog is no executed.

Comment: I just add some more details to my response. As a recommendation it will be good to put such 'small details' like 'some code changes' so that the answer can be more precise.

Comment: Firstly, I am afraid if my question was not correctly expressed. I am not english native speaker. I have completed/edited my ask to try specify my problem.

About your added details, thanks for that, but these were not help me. I removed or changed every references to "login". Also, about "verify if the constraint exist.", If you mean that I have to add a precondition to check this, I cannot do it, because liquibase does not have a precondition to do this. If you mean that I need check if this is created, yes, initial changelog create it but I remove it with my custom changelog (develop db).